# Finding a pair of Orthogonal Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vectors

Want: Pair of orthogonal vectors in $R^4$ that are also orthogonal to the vector (1,1,-2,3)

My attempt at a solution: [image]
I got stuck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got lost in your computations while the answer is quite easy - if you keep in mind what kind of spaces etc. you are manipulating instead of staying at the level of the equations themselves.

First find *any* non-zero vector $b$ orthogonal to $a = \tiny\begin{pmatrix} 1\\1\\-2\\3\end{pmatrix}$. Such a vector is found as an element of the hyperplane with equation $x_1+x_2-2x_3+3x_4 = 0$; you could for instance use $b = \tiny\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$. Now the beauty is that since the space spanned by $a, b$ has dimension two, its orthogonal also has dimension two; therefore, you will certainly be able to find one more vector $c$ orthogonal to both $a$ and $b$, using the same method I used above for $b$. (Left as an exercise for now!).

EDIT: Modified $a$ to match problem statement.

Comment: Would it be (2,2,0,0)? Also why is the equation of the hyperplane $x_1$-$x_2$ instead of $x_1$+$x_2$ ?

Comment: Some typos in my post, sorry. Thanks for Real for fixing them!

Comment: so the two vectors would be (1,-1,0,0) and (2,-2,0,0)??